# How to Custom realtime shader ? (HLSL,Cg,...)

Tags: shaders

i would like to create few shader inside blender that would match inGame shaders from my game engine.
Could someone tell me where and how o start in blender?

thank you

Comment: Maybe osl shaders? You can use them in node system referencing the text/code where they are written. It works with Cycles, CPU only. There are several examples that you can access from the text view (look at the 'templates' menu).

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
But I would like to mimic the render using the same code, with a minimum retakes.
OSL would mean CPU and complete rewriting it doesn't sound like a flexible option for me.